# Form validator closure does not work in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I made a very simple email validator that looks like this:

```
function validateEmail(formControl: FormControl): {[key: string]: any} {
    const regExp = new RegExp(`^[\\w.%+\-]+@[\\w.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,16}$`);
    return regExp.test(formControl.value) ? null : { email: true };
}
```

This works when I add it to the list of validators in the reactive forms approach.

But when I change the above function to:

```
function validateEmail(): ValidatorFn {
    return (formControl: FormControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
        console.log(formControl.value);
        const regExp = new RegExp(`^[\\w.%+\-]+@[\\w.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,16}$`);
        return regExp.test(formControl.value) ? null : { email: true };
    }
}
```

Then the validation does not work. I get no error messages. And the console output shows nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass `control` as `AbstractControl` to your `ValidatorFn`, it means that your code should look as follows:

```
function validateEmail(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
    console.log(control.value);
    const regExp = new RegExp(`^[\\w.%+\-]+@[\\w.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,16}$`);
    return regExp.test(control.value) ? null : { email: true };
  } 
}
```

It should solve your problem, I have very similar validator that is solved like this:

```
export function emailValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
    const email = control.value;

    if ( '' === email || null === email ) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return emailRegEx.test(email) ? null : { invalidEmail: { email } };
    }
  };
}
```

Where `emailRegEx` is defined as a constant outside the function and function returns null also when the passed value is empty string or null.